# Why is the output is incorrect?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have make a Quiz with C# Windows Form with Points. But the output of it is always incorrect. Where could the Problem lie?

```
     int point=0;
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if(right.Checked && !wrong.Checked && !wrong1.Checked && !wrong2.Checked)
            {
                point++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(right1.Checked && !wrong3.Checked && !wrong4.Checked && !wrong5.Checked)
                    {
                    point++;

                    }
                else
                {
                    if (right2.Checked && !wrong6.Checked && !wrong7.Checked)
                    {
                        point++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (right3.Checked && right4.Checked && !wrong8.Checked && !wrong9.Checked)
                        {
                            point++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show($"Your have {point}/5 correct!");
        }
```

Here is the [PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9xN5.jpg) of the Quiz on Windows form(German)!

The output is
`"Your have 1/5 correct!`
even all answers were correct

Comment: Remove all the else statements so every if gets executed no matter what.

Comment: You are using `else` clauses after your `if` which means only ONE of these conditions can ever be true, which means your `point++` can only ever happen once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all your `IF` statements defined as `IF ELSE`

So basically you will only ever get a single point, as only ever 1 of them can be correct.

Remove the `ELSE` and have them just as `IF` statements and it should work.

Comment: Hello Thank you ! I was also little.. I had another question: Is there any way to prevent that the Points double after each time clicking on the button?

Comment: @newbie Either use "point" as a local variable, or reset it to zero before calculating the new result, or disable the button so it can only be clicked once.  Which way is best depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Well your code looks a bit messy. Do you really need to check if the wrong answer are checked ? Why don't you do something like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   checkAnswer(right.Checked)
   checkAnswer(right1.Checked)

   checkAnswer(right2.Checked)

   checkAnswer(right3.Checked)

   checkAnswer(right4.Checked)

   MessageBox.Show($"Your have {point}/5 correct!");
}

public void checkAnswer(boolean answer) {
 if (answer) {
   point++;
 }
}
```

Comment: OP's using checkboxes for three of four questions. They shouldn't but, since they are, yes they need to ensure the user doesn't just tick _all_ answers.

Answer (score -1):

`else` means "otherwise".

The way you've written it, you cannot possibly ever get more than one `point++` executed.

Don't use `else` here.